# PHP Warning with allow_url_include

Tags: php, .htaccess, warnings

I have very strange problem which I can't fix for over a week now. It's about this warning

> PHP Warning:  Adding option (Name: allow_url_include Value: 0) (17, 1) failed!
> in Unknown on line 0

I don't have the allow_url_include option set in any of the files or in .htaccess.

On my local version, I don't have such problem

> PHP Version 5.3.1

On production machine I got the above error, and version of PHP there is also 5.3.1.

I try to set the option in different ways, but nothing removes the warning

> php_flag allow_url_include "yes"
>
> php_flag allow_url_include "1"
>
> php_flag allow_url_include "no"
>
> php_flag allow_url_include "0"

And above 4 examples, but without quotes.

Everything works and I don't see any problems, but I have also

> php_flag log_errors "yes"

So in combination with that and the warning from above it turns kinda bad, since it fills my log errors file with those warnings when someone open the site and for me it's hard to lookup in the file for other problems.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Can you tell us why you wish to enable `allow_url_include`?  Enabling it can result in a huge security hole.

Comment: I want to disabled it, not to enable it. But no matter what I try, it shows that error. For both ways (yes/no) it returns same error (yes, even if it's set to yes, it shows "PHP Warning: Adding option (Name: allow_url_include Value: 0) (17, 1) failed! in Unknown on line 0"

Comment: The problem was syntax error in main server php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was syntax error in main server php.ini

Answer (score 3):

`allow_url_fopen` is a boolean flag.

[Per the PHP manual page on changing runtime configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), the expected syntax seems to be:

```
php_flag allow_url_include off
```

*No quotes*.  It only takes `on` or `off`, not yes or no or 1 or 0.

Comment: It is amazing how much of a mess the php_flag/php_value system is!

Comment: Seriously.  You'd think that they'd either improve the error or improve the list of true/false values to match what the INI file itself and `ini_set` accept.

Comment: Sorry, but setting "php_flag allow_url_include off" doesn't work neither. Still see the same error.

Comment: Can you please edit your original question with your **full, complete, not-edited-in-any-way-whatsoever** `.htaccess` file?

Comment: the problem was with WP's .htaccess file. There was php_flag allow_url_include, but even so I didn't understand why it's added to main log. Anyway... fixed now.